# Mvc route not being matched

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following routes defined in Global.asax.cs:

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // catalog 
    routes.MapRoute("thumbs", "Thumbnail/{extn}/{image}/{width}/{height}", new
    {
        controller = "Image",
        action = "FetchThumbnail",
        extn = "gif",
        image = MediaManager.DefaultImageGuid,
        width = 250,
        height = 200
    });
    routes.MapRoute("rfqlist", "Rfqs/", new { controller = "RfqList", action = "Index" });
    routes.MapRoute("TappDefault", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I cant step through and see them being registered. I have a controller:

```
 public class RfqListController : TappController

  public ActionResult Index(string rfqTitle, int? page)
```

If I call

```
> https://localhost:44300/rfqlist
```

it fires but if I call:

```
> https://localhost:44300/rfqs
```

it 404s. I cant see for looking what Im doing wrong. This is normally so easy.

Comment: Here's the deal: Default parameters in MapRoute are only used if that parameter is not passed in along with the URI. So this means that Rfqs/ is going to Rfqs controller and Index action. It is not going to go to RfqList as defined in your code. I am guessing you don't have an Rfqs controller or may be an Index action so its return 404.Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX#setting_default_values_for_url_parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have a rfqs controller?

`https://localhost:44300/rfqs` matches your default route ("TappDefault") which points to the Index action of rfqs controller

Comment: No I have an RfqList controller as above. I thought that should be matched before TappDefault?